# Running Trajectory Following Example from Autoware.Auto without LGSVL

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to execute/implement the trajectory following example  as listed on the tutorial at Autoware.Auto website (https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/trajectory-following.html)

I have been following the autoware class 2020 provided by Apex.AI.

I am able to run the tutorial for trajectory following using the LGSVL simulator, but I would like to modify the plant environment (LGSVL) and replace it with a different plant environment (that provides it the required sensor [lidar - front and rear] data .

I have gone through the the ROS2 launch.py file that launches the ROS nodes in detail to understand how the nodes are initialized and how they work. If I do not start the simulation (LGSVL) and directly run the ROS2 launch command line to start the trajectory following examples, all ROS2 nodes are generated EXCEPT for the UNITYROS2 node. After further inspection, I found that this node publishes lidar data and subscribes to data from the vehicle etc.

Is there any way that someone could provide me some help as to what needs to be changed (in the python launch file, .yaml configuration file etc. ) in order to run this example using a different simulation platform (plant environment).

PS. I can publish ROS topics from my plant/simulation for the lidars with any name - just need to know what needs to change on the autoware.auto side.

Thanks,

Shlok

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368928/running-trajectory-following-example-from-autoware.auto-without-lgsvl/) by [shlokgoel](https://answers.ros.org/users/67161/shlokgoel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Shlok The `lgsvl_interface` package is the one that translates between messages produced/received by Autoware and those produced/received by LGSVL. Another example of a vehicle interface is also provided in the `ssc_interface` package. Another package similar to these (that inherits from the classes in `vehicle_interface`) will need to be created to interface with your simulator. Once you've done this, we would be happy to review a merge request to see this included in Autoware! See https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/autoware-vehicle-interfaces-design.html for more information.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2021-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1